# import all functions vs. import specific function

Tags: python, import, language-design

In Python,

```
import shutil, os
```

allows me to call `os.environ`, `os.path.exists(folder)`, `os.listdir(pool)`, `shutil.rmtree(folder)` and `shutil.copyree()`. It seems that I call any function, defined in those modules. Nevertheless, I cannot call `ctime()` once I have imported `import time`. I must import `ctime` explicitly, by

```
from time import ctime
```

Why is such inconsistency? I find it difficult to program in such unpredictability.

Comment: `import time; time.ctime()` works for me.

Comment: This is certainly works.

Comment: Sorry, I have realized the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but `time.ctime()` works just *fine*. Did you perhaps use `from time import time` or otherwise rebound `time` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from time import ctime` allows to call `ctime()` directly, without `time.ctime()` prefix. It is me, who was inconsistent comparing fully qualified names `os.listdir()` with `ctime()` alone.

Comment: It's all about namespaces. :)